# How to create a collision in a Snake Game?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently creating a Snake Game in html and java script and i am having difficulties creating a collision where the snake (known as 'myGamePiece' in code)(green block)is not colliding with the obstacle (known as 'myObstacle' in code)(red block) and adding 5 extra blocks to the snake. How could i resolve this issue?

I have tried implementing and editing other pieces of code into my game and have been using the W3 schools game tutorial as part of a guide for my game but it doesn't provide or give a clear solution as what i could for my solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <style>
        canvas {
            border:1px solid #000000;
            background-color: #000000;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body onload="startGame()">
        <script>

        var myGamePiece;
        var myObstacle;

        function startGame() {
            myGamePiece = new component(20, 20, "green", 10, 120);
            myObstacle  = new component(20, 20, "red", 300, 120);    
            myGameArea.start();
        }
    //Creates the Game Canvas:    
        var myGameArea = {
            canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
            start : function() {
                this.canvas.width = 900;
                this.canvas.height = 500;
                this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
                document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
                this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    //create the movement with the KeyBoard Arrows:
                window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
              myGameArea.key = e.keyCode;
            })
            window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
              myGameArea.key = false;
            })
            },
            clear : function() {
                this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
            },

        }

        function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.speedX = 0;
            this.speedY = 0;    
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;    
            this.update = function() {
                ctx = myGameArea.context;
                ctx.fillStyle = color;
                ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            }
            this.newPos = function() {
                this.x += this.speedX;
                this.y += this.speedY;  
         }      

        }

        function updateGameArea() {

            myGameArea.clear();
            myObstacle.update();
            myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
          myGamePiece.speedY = 0; 
          if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 37) {myGamePiece.speedX = -1; }
          if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 39) {myGamePiece.speedX = 1; }
          if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 38) {myGamePiece.speedY = -1; }
          if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 40) {myGamePiece.speedY = 1; }
            myGamePiece.newPos();    
            myGamePiece.update();
        }

        </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

I expect the output to be that when the Game piece collides with the obstacle, 5 more green blocks are added to the end of the game piece, but nothing happens when it collides together.

Comment: Where are you trying to detect a collision? Where are you trying to add those other obstacles?

Comment: You can look through my JS [implementation of snake](https://github.com/Mellen/snakeJS) if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I created simple function `checkCollision()` I suggest you to improve it and calculate if there is collision of object given in parameters and then return true, and handle collision in another function.
In that way you will be able to use the same function to check collision with other objects and don't need to rewrite it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <style>
        canvas {
            border:1px solid #000000;
            background-color: #000000;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body onload="startGame()">
        <script>

        var myGamePiece;
        var myObstacle;

        function startGame() {
            myGamePiece = new component(20, 20, "green", 10, 120);
            myObstacle  = new component(20, 20, "red", 300, 120);    
            myGameArea.start();
        }
    //Creates the Game Canvas:    
        var myGameArea = {
            canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
            start : function() {
                this.canvas.width = 900;
                this.canvas.height = 500;
                this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
                document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
                this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    //create the movement with the KeyBoard Arrows:
                window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
              myGameArea.key = e.keyCode;
            })
            window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
              myGameArea.key = false;
            })
            },
            clear : function() {
                this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
            },

        }

        function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.speedX = 0;
            this.speedY = 0;    
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;    
            this.update = function() {
                ctx = myGameArea.context;
                ctx.fillStyle = color;
                ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            }
            this.newPos = function() {
                this.x += this.speedX;
                this.y += this.speedY;  
         }      

        }

        function updateGameArea() {

            myGameArea.clear();
            myObstacle.update();
            myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
          myGamePiece.speedY = 0; 
          if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 37) {myGamePiece.speedX = -1; }
          if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 39) {myGamePiece.speedX = 1; }
          if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 38) {myGamePiece.speedY = -1; }
          if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 40) {myGamePiece.speedY = 1; }
            myGamePiece.newPos();    
            myGamePiece.update();
          checkCollision(); //check collision
        }
        
        function checkCollision()
        {
            if(Math.abs(myGamePiece.x - myObstacle.x) < myGamePiece.width) //if difference of X of 2 objects is less than with of object, you can replace it with your desired value 
          if(Math.abs(myGamePiece.y - myObstacle.y) < myGamePiece.height) //the same for the height
           console.log("collision"); // handle collision here
        }
        startGame();
        </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

if you got questions don't hesitate to ask